# TCL coding style while creating lists from other list entries

Tags: coding-style, tcl

I have the following lines of code:

```
            set FxGlob  [lindex $GlobSectionForces $i]
            set FyGlob  [lindex $GlobSectionForces $i+1]
            set FzGlob  [lindex $GlobSectionForces $i+2]
            set GlobForces [ list $FxGlob $FyGlob $FzGlob ]
```

That looks uggly to me. I know I could put it all into one set command, not much better.
Is there a "nicer" or "cleaner" way for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like this? Uses `lrange` to strip the list to the 3 values you want and then use lassign to extract those.

```
set GlobForces [lrange $GlobSectionForces $i $i+2]
lassign $GlobForces FxGlob FyGlob FzGlob
```

Comment: Actually, you don't need the `expr`: `lrange` supports _M+N_ indexing, so `lrange $GlobSectionForces $i $i+2` is good.  Also, in case there are only these three items in `GlobSectionForces`, `lrange $GlobSectionForces $i end` works.

Comment: @Hoodiecrow, corrected, I mistakenly thought mathematic expressions where only allowed for end (e.g. `end-2`).

Comment: @KillianDS It depends on the version of Tcl. (We don't make them very efficient as yet; a project for another day I suspect…)

Comment: Afaik, this was changed with Tcl 8.5. For large integers, this is a problem.